# Html.RadioButtonFor for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to survey about the service of my product.

```
1   Was the product or service provided in a timely manner? 
    - Very Satisfied
    - Satisfied
    - Neutral
2   Was the product or service complete and accurate? 
    - Very Satisfied
    - Satisfied
    - Neutral
```

The data are taken from database, and each option use as radio button. I loop data in my views of my asp.net project :

```
  <%      
   foreach (var serviceQ in _question)
   {
  %>
      <%:Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Option, serviceQ.Option1)%>
      <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.Option1) %>
      <%:serviceQ.Option1 %>
      <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Option1) %>

      <%:Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Option, serviceQ.Option2)%>
      <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.Option2) %>
      <%:serviceQ.Option2 %>
      <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Option2) %>

  <%
   }
  %>
```

But the problem is I do this all my radio button has the same name.

I tried in `foreach` block :

```
<%:Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Option + serviceQ.ID, serviceQ.Option1)%>
<%:Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Option + serviceQ.ID, serviceQ.Option2)%>
```

Then got an error : `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

Answer (score 1):

Look at [HtmlHelper.RadioButton Method (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568843%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

```
public IHtmlString RadioButton(
    string name,
    Object value
)
```

You will get something like this:

```
<%:Html.RadioButton(model.Option + serviceQ.ID, serviceQ.Option1)%>
```

Comment: I tried `<%:Html.RadioButton(model => model.Option + serviceQ.ID, serviceQ.Option1)%>` , then I got an error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`.

Comment: @socheata `RadioButton` and `RadioButtonFor` are different methods, second uses lambda (with `=>`) and first string as parameter, to access view model you need to use `Model`.